# Accessing Thread Local Storage

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-local-storage

When 2nd thread executes, it results in exception. Can you pls explain why?

```
class TLS
{
    public void Run()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " started.");
            LocalDataStoreSlot ldss = Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("unique"); // Exception
            Thread.SetData(ldss, "some_data");
            string a = Thread.GetData(ldss) as string;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " ended.");
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Details:

`at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.LocalDataStoreMgr.AllocateNamedDataSlot(String name)
   at ConsoleApplication2.TLS.Run() in AutoLock.cs:line 65
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to allocate a slot with the same name twice. You might want to have a read over the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.allocatenameddataslot.aspx).

**Update**: You should only allocate the slot once - before you start the threads. Do it in your main program. Right now you are doing it everytime a thread starts and that's why you are getting the exception.

Comment: if it is TLS, shouldn't it be unique for each thread. why does every thread use same slot?

Comment: @Azodius: Because you are doing it twice. Just call it once - a slot with that name will be allocated for each thread. Just have a read over the linked MSDN documentation, it explains it.

Comment: Ok. that means when a slot is created, it is created in TLS of every thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.allocatenameddataslot.aspx). You're using it the wrong way basically. You can't allocate a named slot twice:

> If the AllocateNamedDataSlot method is
>   used, it should be called in the main
>   thread at program startup, because it
>   throws an exception if a slot with the
>   specified name has already been
>   allocated. There is no way to test
>   whether a slot has already been
>   allocated.